# Using std::begin() and std::end() to construct vector from array

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am getting error, while trying to construct vector

```
int data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // source
std::vector<int> vv(data, data + 10); // ok 
std::vector<int> vv(std::begin(data), std::end(data + 10)); // Error
```

GCC output:

> main.cpp:59:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘end(int*)’
>
> ```
>  std::vector<int> vv(std::begin(data), std::end(data + 10));
> ```

Why I am getting this error ?

Comment: The point of `std::end` is that you don't have to put in the "random" + 10. Keep in mind you can initialize a vector with an initializer list.

Comment: @chris false, see answer below

Comment: @newprint: Hm, no, that really is the entire point. To get the end of a container or array without explicitly mentioning the bounds of said container or array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting the error because of the `+ 10`, which causes a decay from `array of T` to `pointer to T`. There's an `std::end` overload to take (a reference to) an array, but *not* one to take a pointer.

Just use: `std::vector<int> vv(std::begin(data), std::end(data));`

Alternatively, just use:

```
std::vector<int> vv{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

...and skip using the array at all.

Comment: false, check the furniture 
template< class T, size_t N > T* begin( T (&array)[N] );

Comment: @newprint: Have you tried it? Did you have the compiler set to accept C++11 when you did?

Comment: It is set to C++11, but there is a problem with what you are wrote. `std::end(data)` Carries no information to where the end is !! Unlike other containers type, array have no `.size()`. You can't deduce the size of it !!

Comment: @newprint An illustration: `sizeof(array)` gives the size of the *whole array* in bytes. There's an old trick to get the number of elements: `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`. An array type *does* carry an information about the number of elements it contains. An array is not a pointer.

Comment: @newprint: `std::end(data)` certainly carries information about the size.  It's in the **type**.

Comment: @GManNickG Hi rep doesn't mean all that much... Most of the rep on this site comes from being first to answer on a stupid question for some kid at school. I only come here when I'm bored:) newprint, if you could, please accept Jerry's answer so that I could delete my. I don't like all the idiotic arguments people on SO tend to get into every time they see something that doesn't match their template of thinking. No offence GMan.

Comment: @littleadv I think we were just talking about different things. Of course you cannot use `std::end` on a dynamically allocated array, as you may not have the size information at compile-time. However, `std::end` works on any argument of array type.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use `std::end` on an array when you don't know the size. `std::end` is defined such that it will deduce the size and return a pointer to that offset:

```
std::vector<int> v(begin(data), end(data));
```

Comment: s/don't know/don't want to repeat/